# update name from the list using immutablejs

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, immutable.js

I am having very hard time to understand the documentation of immutablejs. I want to update the list whose name is Sanskar. For that i first tried to use findIndex to find its index and update it using update(). But i am getting an error of item.get() is not a function.

Why i am getting an error of item.get is not a function?

```
const arr = [
             {name: 'Sanskar', age: 24, designation: 'Intern Developer'},
             {name: 'John', age: 28, designation: 'Developer'}
            ]; 
const list1 = Immutable.List.of(arr);

const list2 = list1.findIndex(item => item.get('name') === 'Sanskar');
console.log('list2', list2.toJS());
```

I am practicing immutablejs in jsbin

http://jsbin.com/zawinecutu/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the code below for an example of how to do what you want to do.  The first issue is that you're not building your List correctly, the second is the way you're updating the element in question.

```
const Immutable = require('immutable');
const arr = [
             {name: 'Sanskar', age: 24, designation: 'Intern Developer'},
             {name: 'John', age: 28, designation: 'Developer'}
            ];

// your initial data is an array of objects.  If you want a List of objects:
const list1 = Immutable.List.of(...arr);

// the contents of the list are ordinary JavaScript objects.
const person2Index = list1.findIndex(item => item['name'] === 'Sanskar');

// now you can use the List.get() method:
const person2 = list1.get(person2Index);

person2['designation'] = 'Astronaut';

// do the update like this
const list2 = list1.update(person2Index, p => person2);

console.log(list2.toJS());
```